# Is it possible to edit code while TFS is down

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017

My TFS is down and it is linked to my solution in Visual Studio 2017.

If I edit any files in my solution will this cause an error when I need to check in when the TFS is back up?

I'm getting a prompt that is saying there is write-protection which concerns me.

```
You can either save the file in a different location or Microsoft Visual Studio can attempt to remove the write-protection and overwrite the file in its current location.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to use local workspace not server worksapce when work offline.

> **Work offline with difficulty and with poor performance.**
>
> When you are offline in a server workspace, **you cannot work with
>   your local files because they are read-only until you check them
>   out**. You can check out files only from Solution Explorer, and only
>   after you switch to offline mode (as explained below). While you're
>   offline, you can't perform any other operations, such as add, delete,
>   rename, or undo.

1. Go to `Solution Explorer`
2. Right click on your solution
3. Click `Go online`

More  detailed information on the pros and cons of local and server workspaces, please refer our official [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/decide-between-using-local-server-workspace?view=azure-devops). If above solution still not work, suggest to restart whole  Visual Studio, which should do the trick.